# forward declaration property Class A->B, B->A

Tags: objective-c

I want to have an @property Class A in class B, and @property Class B in class A.

It's my situation:

Class A (Inherits SNCNode):
-in classA.h:

```
@class classB;

@property classB foo1;

@end
```

-in classA.m:

```
#import "classB"
```

Class B(Inherits SCNNode):

-in classB.h:

```
#import "classA"

@property classA foo2;

@end
```

-in classB:

```
#import "classA"
```

MainViewController:
-in MainViewController.m:

```
ClassB *b = [[ClassB alloc] init];

b.foo2.foo1 = ...;
```

But when I want to set property foo1 in class B by my property foo2 i got an exception:
NSInvalidArgumentException - unrecognized selector sent to instance

I mean(In class B):
self.foo2.foo1 = ...;

How to fix it if it's even possible?

[EDIT]
Exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SCNNode setMyZombie:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e8b530'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x27b505f7 0x35604c77 0x27b55abd 0x27b53999 0x27a84b88 0x72963 0x6ea01 0x2aff846d 0x2aff81dd 0x2affe0a7 0x2affbaff 0x2b065d91 0x2b257dc1 0x2b25a219 0x2b264ac9 0x2b258abb 0x2e2700c9 0x27b16ffd 0x27b162c1 0x27b14a5f 0x27a61b31 0x27a61943 0x2b05c8f7 0x2b0576f1 0x75639 0x35ba0aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Paste in the exact error message.

Comment: I added in main post.

Comment: @MuniekMg - That exception says you've sent a message to an object that doesn't support it, e.g. you sent a message recognised by `A` to an instance of `B`. Check your assignments to your properties carefully, it looks like you've mixed up your `A`'s and `B`'s. You are going to have to post actual code (after narrowing the problem down) for anyone to be able to provide detailed help.

Comment: The exception tells you that `SCNNode` does not have a method called `setMyZombie:`.  Did you somehow prevent the compiler from auto-generating the method?

Comment: The error message shows that your problem has nothing whatever to do with the forward declaration. The forward declaration is working perfectly. The problem lies elsewhere. You are not showing the code that causes the crash so there's no more to be said.

Comment: I've edited "it's my situation" in main post.

Yes, SCNNode has't method setMyZombie but I don't use SCNNode's object but ClassA(inherits SCNNode) which has @property myZombie, so  this class has setMyZombie method. In this case its "setFoo1".

Comment: Set a breakpoint on all Objective-C exceptions.  Show us the stack trace when it gets to this error.

Comment: The problem was down casting, that's why it didn't see my method, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear what your problem is, here is a guess:

You can forward declare a class in Objective-C with `@class <name>;`. For example in your `B.h`:

```
@class A;  // forward declare A

@interface B

@property A foo2

@end
```

In your implementations of both `A` and `B` you should import both headers.

HTH

Comment: I did it, but then when I want to set foo1 by propetry foo1 (self.object.foo2.foo1 = ...; I gon an exception: Terminating app due to uncaught exception like in my question (edited)

Comment: @MuniekMg - this guess at your problem looks to be wrong, see comment on main question